# Dynamic Data in Drop down

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want  to have a  drop down the contains the quantity in such a way that if the number of products in stock is 45 then the drop down will show counting from 1-45 in drop down  and if suppose 5 products are sold out then the drop down will show 1-40

how this is possible

Comment: Are you generating an HTML form with PHP?  You have hist post tagged "ajax"; are you looking for a Javascript solution that will call back to your PHP app and set up the dropdown?

What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your PHP you would query the database to findout how many products are left in stock.

for example:

```
   select in_stock from products where id = '$id';
```

then on your php you can do something like

```
$in_stock_q = mysql_query("select in_stock from products where id = '$id'");
$in_stock_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($in_stock_q);
$in_stock = $in_stock_r['in_stock'];

printf("<select name=\"in_stock\">");
for($i=1;$i<$in_stock;$i++) {
    printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $i, $i);
}
printf("</select>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the number of products stored in $numInStock you can generate a dropdown as follows.

```
<select>
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numInStock; $i++){
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```